# C++11 binding rules for const &&

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, rvalue-reference

Many people do not know that `const` rvalue references are part of the C++11 language. [This](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/) blog post discusses them but appears to be mistaken regarding the binding rules. Quoting the blog:

```
struct s {};

void f (      s&);  // #1
void f (const s&);  // #2
void f (      s&&); // #3
void f (const s&&); // #4

const s g ();
s x;
const s cx;

f (s ()); // rvalue        #3, #4, #2
f (g ()); // const rvalue  #4, #2
f (x);    // lvalue        #1, #2
f (cx);   // const lvalue  #2
```

> Note the asymmetry: while a const lvalue reference can bind to an rvalue, 
>   a const rvalue reference cannot bind to an lvalue. In
>   particular, this makes a const lvalue reference able to do everything
>   a const rvalue reference can and more (i.e., bind to lvalues).

The comments on the sample code appear to check out on my installation of GCC 4.9 (with -std=c++14 flag set). So, contrary to the blog text, is it true that `const &&` should bind to `const &` and `const &&` and `const &` only bind to `const &`? If not what is the actual rule?

---

Here is a demo that appears to show `const &&` binding to `const&` in GCC 4.9: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/794bbb911d00596e

Comment: `const &&` can bind **only** to rvalues (ie `const &&` and `&&`). The blog is right in text.

Comment: @bolov, please check the demo. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, that is a `const &` binding to a `const &&`

Comment: Your demo doesn't contradict anything. When we are talking about binding, we are talking about *reference binding*. A rvalue-reference to const is an rvalue and rvalues can bind to lvalue-references to const. `g()` in your example returns an rvalue (not an rvalue-reference as you thought) so it is allowed to bind to #2. In the quote, the author is talking about the *parameter type*, not the argument.

Comment: @0x499602D2, OK, so I merely misunderstood the direction of binding?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion, whatever you've stated after *contrary to the blog text* is not contradicting anything, you're reiterating what the blog says, except you have the order of the parameter types of binding preference for a `const&&` argument flipped.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Yes, binding happens the other way.

Comment: @Praetorian, it appears that I merely misunderstood the sense of the word binding. Because of the way the code comments list function overloads, I thought the author meant binding in the sense of overload resolution. So, is could the question still be valuable to anyone or should it delete it?

Comment: Considering "binding" is the word used for both directions, I think this is a question worth keeping (unless it's a duplicate) and worth answering in a way that explains the confusion. You're certainly not the first to get confused by this.

Comment: I seem to remember an earlier question about `const&&`, but can't find it. If you can, and it's a dupe, go ahead and close it. Otherwise I agree with hvd that this is worth keeping. But please do post what you've learnt in an answer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 *"A rvalue-reference to const is an rvalue"* I find this confusing; what's the context?

Comment: @dyp Nevermind that part. I guess I should've said rvalues can bind to lvalue-references to const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'binding' in this context means tying a reference to a particular object.

```
int a;

int &b = a; // the reference is 'bound' to the object 'a'

void foo(int &c);

foo(a); // the reference parameter is bound to the object 'a'
        // for this particular execution of foo.
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e081b59b5e76e03

So then reading the quote:

> Note the asymmetry: while a const lvalue reference can bind to an rvalue,

```
void foo(int const &);

foo(1); // the const lvalue reference parameter is bound to
        // the rvalue resulting from the expression '1'
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12722f2b38c74c75

> a const rvalue reference cannot bind to an lvalue.

```
void foo(int const &&);

int a;

foo(a); // error, the expression 'a' is an lvalue; rvalue
        //references cannot bind to lvalues
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccadc5307135c8e8

> In particular, this makes a const lvalue reference able to do everything a const rvalue reference can and more (i.e., bind to lvalues).

```
void foo(int const &);

foo(1); // const lvalue reference can bind to rvalue

int a;
foo(a); // and lvalue
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5553c99e182c89b

Comment: It is not observable, but when binding `1` to an `int const&`, a temporary object is created that is initialized with `1`, and that temporary object is bound to the reference. prvalue expressions of fundamental type are *values*, they don't have addresses.

Comment: @dyp you get a similar temporary object when binding `1` to an rvalue reference: you can take the address of an rvalue parameter initialized with `1` (rvalue reference variables produce lvalue expressions, confusingly enough...) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2c67961cf15072c