# Extending lifetime of temporary - proper way

Tags: c++

Say I have:

```
f(T& t){ ... }
```

which I sometimes want to provide argument for from a function call

```
T GetT() { ... }
```

like this:

```
f(GetT())
```

Which won't compile even though I'm convinced that the lifetime of `T` is guaranteed to last until the end of expression, I also cannot change the `T&` to `const T&` because I need to modify the object inside `f`.
I thought about using `T&&` but then when I happen to have lvalue of `T` I would need to `move()` it, which would make it awkward because I sometimes need to use `T` after the call to `f`. In my case `T` is plain old data so I guess it would work but it doesn't feel right to move an object and use it afterwards.

Is there an elegant way to allow function to take both rval and lval refs to mutable object?

ATM I'm just doing

```
T t = GetT();  
f(t);
```

Which I feel is at least one useless line and one useless copy of `T`.

Comment: Change `f(T& t){ ... }` to `f(T t){ ... }`

Comment: The reason why you cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference is to stop you from modifying an object that will soon go out of scope.

Comment: @RichardCritten That would make redundant copies. Also i could not observe the changes f made on T.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the object inside `f`? There's no way to get to that modified object, so what purpose does modifying it serve?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sometimes i call the function with an lvalue, then i can see the changes. Its really at the discretion of the caller to decide if hes interested in changes made onto T.

Comment: @user1316208 Then the caller needs to indicate here that he's not interested in the changes rather than making it look like the caller had no idea there were any changes.

Comment: @Mohamad Elghawi - A common and incorrect misconception. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231626/why-are-you-not-allowed-to-bind-a-rvalue-reference-to-a-non-const-reference-but

Comment: @MikeVine Wow! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Not sure if you would consider it elegant but it would look something like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
};

template<class T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<MyStruct, 
                  typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, "ERROR");
    t.i = 1024;
}

MyStruct GetMyStruct()
{
    return MyStruct();
}

int main() 
{
    foo(GetMyStruct());

    MyStruct ms;
    foo(ms);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The proper terminology is now "forwarding references".

Answer (score 1):

The way that you're currently doing, i.e. storing the object in a variable, is a proper way to extend the lifetime of the returned object and allow non-const references to bind to it. If `GetT` is implemented so that (N)RVO is possible, then no useless copy need to be made because it can be [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my problem with simple overload:

f(T& t) { ... }
f(T&& t) { f(t); }

But there still has to be a better way.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bind a reference to a temporany: only const reference can do that.

I suggesto you to look this link [C++11 binding rules for const &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760290/c11-binding-rules-for-const)

Comment: I'm aware of that. Somehow you missed the question.